# Use FusedBatchNorm C++ API

Tags: tensorflow

Probably a dumb question. I construct graph using Tensorflow C++ API. Was able to train the graph for image recognition/classification. Now I want to add `BatchNorm` layer to the graph, but not sure how to do it. We have `FusedBatchNorm` operation, and a `FusedBatchNormGrad` operator. How do I associate the grad operator for backprop? Thanks.